# Passing ajax request to a servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have the following jquery function. When I click on a row of the table, I get the first td of every row that correspond to the hidden row

```
<td class="my_route" style="display: none">${route.id_route}</td>
```

then the `route.id_route` is passed correctly to ajax and this value should be passed to servlet `admin_show_reservations`. The value has been retrieved correctly because it is showed in the alert. What I don't have is the requested page.Why?Maybe the ajax function is not properly made

**JQUERY**

```
$(".reserv_row").click(function() {
var href = $(this).find(".my_route").text();
alert("href is----"+href);
 $.ajax({
                cache:false,
                dataType:"html",
                data:"id="+href,
                type: "POST",
                url: "admin_show_reservations"

                });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="show_reservations">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Compagnia</th>
                        <th>ID Veivolo</th>
                        <th>Partenza</th>
                        <th>Arrivo</th>
                        <th>Ora partenza (ora locale)</th>
                        <th>Ora arrivo (ora locale)</th>
                        <th>Classe</th>
                    </tr>
                    <c:forEach items="${routes_list}" var="route">
                        <tr class="reserv_row">
                            <td class="my_route" style="display: none">${route.id_route}</td>
                            <td>${route.airlane}</td>
                            <td>${route.aircraft_id}</td>
                            <td>${route.airport_city_source.city}</td>
                            <td>${route.airport_city_dest.city}</td>
                            <td><fmt:formatDate value="${route.departure_date}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"/></td>
                            <td><fmt:formatDate value="${route.arrival_date}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"/></td>
                            <td>${route.travel_class}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
```

Comment: nothing is changed...

Answer (score 0):

the "data" in ajax success will have everything that you have returned from your servlet

Note : in your case response type should be html.

set the response using PrintWriter

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

  out.write("<h1 class='yourclass'>" + "Hello world" + "</h1>");

  out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a success function to do something with the HTML you get back.

```
$.ajax({
    cache:false,
    // etc
    success: function (myHTML) {
        alert(myHTML);
    }
});
```